# What CRS is used in exif?

Tags: gis, exif

Does [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) specify a specific coordinate reference system like the [WSG-84](https://epsg.io/4326)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exif uses "GPS" on the names, so I would expect WGS-84.

In any case, the [Exif 2012](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf), page 73:

> **GPSMapDatum** Indicates  the  geodetic  survey  data  used  by  the  GPS  receiver.  If  the  survey  data  is  restricted  to  Japan, the  value  of  this  tag  is  'TOKYO'  or  '**WGS-84**'.  If  a  GPS  Info  tag  is  recorded,  it  is  strongly  recommended that this tag be recorded.

so you should check that field, and I would expect to see always *WGS-84*.

Comment: WGS-84, like it is written in you link (but I also wrote one SVG, so I edited the answer). Probably you should edit the question.